Black Text Not Displaying as CMYK in Acrobat Preview
I'm facing an issue when exporting a file from InDesign to PDF and would like to ask for your help in resolving it. In InDesign, I have set the black text to be 100% black (C=0, M=0, Y=0, K=100). However, when I open the PDF in Adobe Acrobat Pro and check the output preview, the black text is showing as DeviceRGB instead of CMYK.
Here are the steps I've followed:

Configured my document in InDesign to CMYK color mode.
In the Swatches panel, I set the black text color to C=0, M=0, Y=0,
K=100.
During PDF export, I used the following settings:

Color Conversion: Convert to Destination (Preserve Numbers)
Destination: Working CMYK - U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2
PDF/X-4:2010
Disabled Optimize for Fast Web View

In Adobe Acrobat Pro, I checked Print Production > Output Preview
and the black text appears as DeviceRGB.
In the Transparency Blend Space settings, I selected CMYK.
In the Appearance of Black settings, it's configured to "Display All
Blacks Accurately".

I've watched several tutorials and checked various settings, but I still can't resolve the issue. Has anyone faced this problem or knows what might be causing it? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.
Best regards,

Have you also enabled Output All Blacks Accurately?
